# Ecto - automatically capitalizing fields

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have an ecto model named `Company` which has an `name` field. What I want is before inserting or updating a company in the database is to apply `String.capitalize` to the name attribute. These are the `create` and `update` functions of `CompanyController`:

```
def create(conn, %{"company" => company_params}) do
  case Company.insert(conn.assigns.current_user, company_params) do
    {:ok, _company} ->
      redirect(conn, to: company_path(conn, :index))

    {:error, changeset} ->
      render(conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset)
  end
end
def update(conn, %{"id" => company_id, "company" => company_params}) do
  company = Company.get(company_id)

  case Company.update(company, company_params) do
    {:ok, _company} ->
      redirect(conn, to: company_path(conn, :show, company))

    {:error, changeset} ->
      render(conn, "edit.html", company: company, changeset: changeset)
  end
end
```

Comment: So like `company_params = Map.update(company_params, "name", &String.capitalize/1)`?

Comment: @Dogbert doesn't `Map.update` have 4 arguments?

Comment: Oops you're right. I meant `Map.update!`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done simply by using [Map.update!](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html#update!/3) function, either in a separate function of a controller:

```
def create(conn, %{"company" => company_params}) do
  case Company.insert(conn.assigns.current_user, with_capitalized_name(company_params)) do
    {:ok, _company} ->
      redirect(conn, to: company_path(conn, :index))

    {:error, changeset} ->
      render(conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset)
  end
end

def update(conn, %{"id" => company_id, "company" => company_params}) do
  company = Company.get(company_id)

  case Company.update(company, with_capitalized_name(company_params)) do
    {:ok, _company} ->
      redirect(conn, to: company_path(conn, :show, company))

    {:error, changeset} ->
      render(conn, "edit.html", company: company, changeset: changeset)
  end
end

def with_capitalized_name(company_params)
  Map.update!(company_params, "name", &String.capitalize/1)
end
```

Or in a function which is used for casting and validating params (usually called `changeset`):

```
def changeset(company, attrs) do
  company
  |> cast(attrs, [:name])
  |> capitalize(attrs, :name)
end

defp capitalize(_, attrs, field) do
  Map.update!(attrs, field, &String.capitalize/1)
end
```